# How to save images in dynamic folder?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, image-processing

first python script generating folder based on request. second script giving similar image and saving in generated folder. While in multiple request, images is not saving as per request.Only images saving in first folder generated. for example if three concurrent request came it generated 3 folders.but all result is saving in first folder other 2 folders is empty.so second and third user not getting result.

1st Script

```
@app.route('/imageUploads', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_img():

    import secrets 
    import string 
    N = 9

    res = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) 
                                                  for i in range(N)) 


    print("The generated random string : " + str(res)) 
    timesearch = str(res)


    randomvariable = timesearch




    result = 'static/' + randomvariable

    globe = result;

    if not gfile.Exists(result):
        result = 'static/' + randomvariable


        os.mkdir(result)
    #shutil.rmtree(result)
    else:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(result):
            for file in files:
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))

    if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'GET':
        print(request.method)
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:

            print('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']
        #print(file.filename)
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':

            print('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):

            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            #filename = file.filename
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            inputloc = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

            recommend(inputloc, extracted_features,randomvariable)
            #os.remove(inputloc)
            #label = label1.replace("\n", "")
            # name = os.path.basename(pred_final[neighbor])
            image_path = randomvariable

            image_list =[os.path.join(image_path,file) for file in os.listdir(result)
                              if not file.startswith('.')]
            image_list = [k.replace("\\","/") for k in image_list]
)
            images = []
            resultImages = []
            for i, image in enumerate(image_list):

                v = len(image_list)
                print(v,"number of images are")
                images.append({'path': 'https://localhost:5000/'+image, 'fileName': os.path.basename(image)})


                resultImages.append(os.path.basename(image))

                with open('data.json', "w") as f:
                    json.dump({"resultImages": resultImages}, f)
```

---

2nd python script

```py
def get_top_k_similar(image_data, pred, pred_final, k=10):



    result = 'static/' + recommend.randomString



    # cosine calculates the cosine distance, not similiarity. Hence no need to reverse list
    top_k_ind = np.argsort([cosine(image_data, pred_row) \
                        for ith_row, pred_row in enumerate(pred)])[:k]
    print(top_k_ind)



    for i, neighbor in enumerate(top_k_ind):
        image = ndimage.imread(pred_final[neighbor])

        name = os.path.basename(pred_final[neighbor])



        name = os.path.join('static', recommend.randomString, name)
        imsave(name, image)
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Any chance of reducing that to a [mre] - with emphasis on the minimum needed to reproduce the problem? Your examples include unidentified  modules, functions, decorators, etc. . Make a toy example and provide *fake* data if needed - the easier you make it to copy from your question then paste in our editors and execute the more responses you will get.